# Xpath, a range between two values, how?

Tags: xpath

I have a question about filtering a datafeed with an Xpath.
What I want:
I want to select all the products between 30% en 50% percent discount.
What I’ve already tried after reading this website and didn’t work:
`/node[price div price_from from<=.7 to<=.5]`
`/node[price div price_from from <=.7 to <=.5]`
`node[price div price_from @from <=.7 and .5 <= @to]`
`/node[price div price_from from <=”.7” to <=”.5”]`
I don’t know what I could try more. Does anyone has a solution for my headache caused problem?

Thank you!

Comment: please provide an input XML.

Comment: Please also define "didn't work." Did it give an error message? What was the message? Or did it return a value you believe is wrong? What value did you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming XML input like this:

```
<nodes>
    <node>
        <price>30</price>
        <price_from>60</price_from>
    </node>
</nodes>
```

The following XPath expression will match the nodes that have been discounted anywhere between 30 and 50 percent. It's pretty straightforward, you had the correct idea, just needed to fix the syntax:

```
//node[(price div price_from >= 0.5) and (price div price_from <= 0.7)]
```