# Pick a random date and not a specific one in datePickerDay

Tags: xpath, random

My current XPath is:

```
//div[@class="datePickerDay " and text()='17']
```

But I'd like to variate from 1 to 29.

What is the fastest way to accomplish this?
What I would like is to pick a random date between 1 and 29 instead of each time the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225249/xpath-a-range-between-two-values-how might helpful to you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5119850/1305969 may also inspire your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can use comparison operators with `and` like this:

```
//div[@class="datePickerDay" and ((text() >= 17) and (text() <= 29))]
```

[**Demo**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22datePickerDay%22%3E16%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22datePickerDay%22%3E17%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22datePickerDay%22%3E26%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22datePickerDay%22%3E27%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22datePickerDay%22%3E28%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22datePickerDay%22%3E29%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22datePickerDay%22%3E30%3C%2Fdiv%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22datePickerDay%22%20and%20((text()%20%3E%3D%2017)%20and%20(text()%20%3C%3D%2029))%5D&=%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22datePickerDay%22%20and%20((text()%20%3E%3D%2017)%20and%20(text()%20%3C%3D%2029))%5D&input-format=html&printed-node-format=html&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2)

Or for even more complex input a regex approach (not the right solution here):

```
//div[@class="datePickerDay" and matches(text(),'1[789]|2[1-9]')]
```